# Why can't desoldering wick be used to desolder SMD?

Tags: soldering, surface-mount

I've read and [heard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVxnINYrsBs) (in German, as spoken in Austria) that desoldering SMD components with desoldering wick does *not* work.

Why?

Side note: I wouldn't care if the PCB is destroyed. I want the component.

Comment: You're right to warn about that guy's accent. 8 years of my life learning German, and that guy may as well have been speaking Swedish. "Keine Chance".

Comment: @ThePhoton It's even hard for me, a native German speaker. I listened again, more carefully. What I understand: "Litzen kann nur's Zinn wegsaugen, aber unter die Hacksen bleibt's noch", meaning that the wick can not remove the solder underneath the pins. What's irritating is that he says: "Was passiert ist, die Print ist hin, Chip ist auch raus", meaning that the chip will be removed but the PCB is toast. In fact this would be perfect for me since I want the component. Anyhow, please *don't* use this for learning German. ;-)

Comment: I would interpret "Chip ist auch raus" as "the chip is also beyond any hope of re-use". (I'm Dutch, that's almost Germany-by-the-Northsea. Just don't tell my fellow countrymen.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it *does* work to a degree.  However, with multi-lead components you may need to get more of the solder off than the wick can pull - contacts perfectly seated on the PCB may have solder retention "pull" the rivals that of the wick.  Even a small chip resistor or capacitor can be difficult to non-destructively remove while heating with a single tip iron (and while destructively digging it off often works, you risk damaging the board).

Some options:

- A hot air station is one of the best tools, cheap ones go for around $100 now.
- There are also dual-tip tweezer irons for removing chip resistors/capacitors.  These cause less damage to surrounding components/housings than hot air may, so if you do a lot of analog prototyping where you are changing components values they can be worth the $50-60.
- for a chip resistor/capacitor, you can try to add enough solder to bridge the component and thus heat both sides at the same time
- sliding a fine wire under SMT IC leads can help you lift them one at a time - music wire from a hobby shop specializing in gram-class aircraft is ideal
- low temperature solder is sold which alloys with the existing solder to lower its melting point, however the possible alloying elements are either extremely expensive or substantially more toxic than lead.

Even with many of the other methods for removal, you may end up reaching for the wick to clean up the pads before installing a replacement.

Comment: I would add using two soldering irons at a pinch does work. But I do wonder how much this would damage the component due to differences in the heat caused by the different irons. Only suitable for two terminal components tho.

Comment: The difference in heat between two irons is likely to be a lot less than the difference in heat between the end you are working on with a single iron and the other end.  Of course most of the time such components are heated uniformly by production equipment and don't encounter irons at all.  At any rate, usually there's little desire to recover a passive chip resistor or capacitor, unless you are trying to measure a mystery capacitor or diagnose a failure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a soldering station "on the cheap" (with temperature control (creep up from 350c.)) and a little initial patience.
1) Long nose pliers
2) #14 solid copper wire
3) Spare soldering tip
4) 1/16 drill bit (you may need to hog out the hole a bit)

Drill hole through tip and thread wire through it (cut wire long).
Bend away from tip toward board.
Keep tip to where wire lands on the board as close as possible.
Bend each side at 90 degrees to form the shape of the chip.
Trim excess wire.
Dont forget to tin the wire (especially at the tip juction you just made) and flux the chip (use rework flux).

OR: You can do what I just did and break down and get a hot air rework station from eBay for under $50.00. It sounds like your in to it -so treat yourself right!

The Hack I just described is fun and it does work. ;)
-e